# Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a `NSManagedObject` class which I'm using to save and retrieve from core-data.

```
class Nickname: NSManagedObject {

func saveData(addressDetails:[String:AnyObject]){
    var isDataSaved = false
    let address = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Nickname",
                                    inManagedObjectContext: appDelegate.managedObjectContext) as! Nickname
    if let addressString = addressDetails["address"] as? String{
        if let addressNickName = addressDetails["nickname"] as? String{
            if let addressID = addressDetails["id"] as? String{
                address.address = addressString
                address.nickname = addressNickName
                address.addressID = addressID
                do{
                    try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.save()
                    isDataSaved = true
                }
                catch{
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if !isDataSaved{
        NSLog("Data not saved in core data. Check Nickname ManagedObject class")
    }
}

func getData(nickName:String)->String?{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Nickname")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "nickname = %@", nickName)
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    var result : [AnyObject]!
    do{ result = try appDelegate.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)}
    catch { print(error)}
    let requiredData = result[0] as? Nickname
    return  requiredData != nil ? (requiredData!.address) : (nil)
}

}
```

In the viewController that I'm performing save and fetch I'm creating an object like this

```
    let table = Nickname()
    let params = ["address":"aasdadad","nickname":"asdadadadad","id":"69"]
    table.saveData(params)
    let data = table.getData("asdadadadad")
    print(data)
```

But I keep getting the error

`CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'XXXX.Nickname'`

I understand that it is happening because I haven't created an object in the right way. I have been searching for a while and haven't been able to find a solution.

**NOTE**: There are many questions in SO regarding the same error. I tried all the suggested solutions and still haven't found a way to fix this.

Comment: Error is thrown by `getData` or `saveData`?

Comment: I think you are intilializing Nickname the wrong way,  **If you instantiate a managed object directly, you must call the designated initializer (init(entity:insertInto:)**  see (apple documentation)[https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject]

Comment: You cannot initialize a `NSManagedObject` instance with the default initializer   `Nickname()`. You must use the designated initializer. By the way : `result` in `getData` is guaranteed to be `[Nickname]` and is never `nil`. Don't use the unspecified `[AnyObject]`.

Comment: PS: And if an error occurs in `getData` the app will crash reliably.

Comment: @vadian It's not crashing in `getData` or `saveData`. I called the functions in `viewDidLoad()` of a UIViewController class. It's crashing when the control exits `viewDidLoad()`. And thanks for pointing out that it will never be nil.

Comment: @OmerMalik The link you posted is throwing a 404 error

Comment: I wasn't say it does crash in `getData` but it will if an error occurs in the `do` block, because `result` is `nil`. **Never** continue after `catch` with *good* code. put it in the `do` scope.